# Get point from cicumference with angle and other two points

Tags: geometry

How it's possible to get both coordinates x and y from Pb(x,y) having only two points (Center C(x,y) and Point A Pa(x,y)) and an angle alpha in degrees, like show on the following image.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Is $P_a$ always like shown in the image, thus having coordinates $(cx, cy+r)$ or can it be any vector from the center point to a point on the circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a tag for each coordinate for easier labeling rather than for the entire point as mentioned ... for center C, point A, point B respectively as

$$ (xc,yc); \, (xa, ya); \, (xb,yb ) ; $$

so that we  have a combination of x-, y- coordinates:

$$ (xb,yb ) = (xc,yc) + r * ( \sin \frac{t^0 \pi}{180 }, \cos \frac{t^0 \pi}{180 }). $$

Or, if you like it separately written out,then

$$ xb  = xc + r *  \sin \frac{t^0 \pi}{180 }, \, yb  = yc + r *  \cos \frac{t^0 \pi}{180 }. $$

Answer (score 1):

All points on that given circle can be described by the vector equation
$$
(x, y) = (cx, cy) + r (\sin \alpha, \cos\alpha)
$$
where the second summand is the vector starting from the center point $(cx, cy)$ with endpoint on the circle of radius $r$, having an angle $\alpha$ to $P_a = (cx, cy + r)$.

In other words: one rotates $P_a$ by angle $\alpha$ around $(cx, cy)$ to get $P_b$.

This just needs the coordinates of the center point $(cx, cy)$, the coordinates of $P_a = (pax, pay)$ and the angle $\alpha$.

The radius $r$ can determined via
$$
r = \sqrt{(pax - cx)^2 + (pay - cy)^2}
$$
Note: This assumes $P_a$ is always $(cx, cy + r)$.